# How to import information from sheets in another Document based on two values? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 documents:

**Document 1** contains a list with so called Set-names, displayed as "Set". And within each "Set" there is name that can be found that corresponds to the number within that set.

**Document 2** contains all the Set-names with each their own numbers and Name. Each Set-name has it's own Sheet, and there is a lot of them.

I want to fill in just the Set-name "Set" and Set-number "Set#", to automatically display the name corresponding to these two values. The question is however, how do I do that?

### Document 1: Collection

Shared document link: [Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15C7RSEQ7aJToBYjL14QLqExHHcy4mTwPXoulZbaSRxQ/edit?usp=sharing) (File > Make copy)

[image: Document 1: Collection]

### Document 2: All Set-names

Shared document link: [Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8iWAl7ZQhsue6Opefvh_9yDwMk06PvqUdQoVuEJw00/edit?usp=sharing) (File > Make copy)

[image: Document 2: All Set-names]

In this example above I would like to output "Dark Raichu" within Document 1 at Q74:T74 and at Q75:T75. Is this even possible to make? [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?rd=1) might help as well so I don't have to manually edit each Set-name. Any idea/suggestion/solution is much appreciated!

Comment: So you basically want to import the data from one Spreadsheet regarding Raichu to another Spreadsheet right? If so, what range from your Document 2 you want to export to Document 1?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf That's correct! The range from Document 2 will be A5:A. However, Each Set has it's own sheet which is the exact name displayed under the Set column. In this case row 74 from Document 1 needs to look up in Document 2 > 'Team Rocket'! > A5:A, which will output Dark Raichu on Document 1 > Q73 and Q74.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **EDIT**

*(following OP's explanations)*

First of all I have to say that **you should AVOID making such radical changes to the original question, since it completely throws readers off balance**.

Having said that there is a completely different approach that should be followed.

#### In your Document 2: All Set-names

**Step 1**
Go to your `Wizards Black Star Promos` tab.
Using a formula like  `=ArrayFormula(A4:A59&"/555")`
change the `Set #` from `1,2,3...59` to `1/555,2/555,3/555...59/555`
*(`555` can be any unique number that does NOT conflict with the other sets)*

**Step 2**
Create a new tab. Name this tab `AllSets`

**Step 3**
Use this formula in cell `A2`

```
={FILTER('Base Set'!A5:C,'Base Set'!A5:A<>"");
  FILTER(Fossil!A5:C,Fossil!A5:A<>"");
  FILTER('Base Set 2'!A5:C,'Base Set 2'!A5:A<>"");
  FILTER('Wizards Black Star Promos'!A5:C,'Wizards Black Star Promos'!A5:A<>"");
  FILTER(Jungle!A5:C,Jungle!A5:A<>"")}
```

Using this pattern complete the formula for the rest of your tabs. You will end up with a 3 columns list of **all your sets in one place**.

#### In your Document 1: Collection

**Step 4**
Go to your `Collection` tab.
In cell `Q2` (where column `Q` is **exactly before** your `Name` column `R`) use the following formula.
*(As before, complete the formula for the rest of your tabs)*

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(N2:N&(SWITCH(H2:H, 
                          "Base Set","/96",
                          "Jungle","/64",
                          "Wizards Black Star Promos","/555",
                          "Fossil","/62"))))
```

This way you will bring the complete `Set #` back.
This will be our helper column which can be hidden and will be only used in the next formula.

**Step 5**
In the same `Collection` tab and in cell `R2` place this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(
        VLOOKUP(Q2:Q,IMPORTRANGE("1n8iWAl7ZQhsue6Opefvh_9yDwMk06PvqUdQoVuEJw00","AllSets!A2:C"),{2,3},0)))
```

[image]

The above final formula will give you everything.
The Card name, the Type as well as the Link and the Image of the card.
If you do not want the Type just change this part of the formula `{2,3}` to just `2`.

**Step 6**
Enjoy :)

*Additional functions used:*

- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`SWITCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690)

---

**Original answer**
*(For the question as [originally posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66411344/1) )*

You can use a combination formula like

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(
        VLOOKUP(V2:V,{REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!R2:R,"\d+")*1,Sheet1!S2:S},2,0)))
```

*(do adjust ranges and locale syntax to meet your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Thnx for taking a look! That's really close to what I'm looking for, but somehow I can't make it work. I've edited my question to explain it better.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: *(After having a second look at your edited question.)* How could this ever have any similarities to your original question!!!! LOL Anyway.. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I've added a link to my question. Thnx again for taking a look!

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question again  or at my Document 1 link where I try your method in sheet 'Practise' C1? I can't get it to work

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N2:N,{REGEXEXTRACT('{INDIRECT(H2)}'!A:A,"\d+")*1,'{INDIRECT(H2)}'!B:B,"\d+"},2,0)))` This isn't working but I think you can read what I try to achieve here? It would be even better if an `IMPORTRANGE` can be added so I don't have to manually import all the sheets in the same document.

Comment: Thank you so m much! Brilliant approach and I'll try avoiding radical changes in the future! I skipped step 1 because I can't get that to work (I'm still a Formula-Noob) and just added /555 after every number myself (quickly being done in Visual Studio Code), but after step 5, it won't show me any text. Not even an error. Do I need to change a setting or anything to make it work?

Comment: I got it working now, thank you so much! =D

Comment: @Jonathan It would be nice to also award the bounty. If  you don't, it is just wasted. You just lose your points and no one collects them :(

Answer (score -1):

You can easily import a range from one Spreadsheet to another using [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en). IN your case described as you wanted to import the range `A5:A` (i.e all cells in column `A` minus the first 5 cells in the column) of the sheet `Team Rocket` of the Spreadsheet `Document 2` into `Document 1` cell `Q73` you would need to use this function in cell `Q73`:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("YOUR DOCUMENT 2 SPREADSHEET URL","Team Rocket!A5:A")
```

> Note that when you first use this function it might ask you to grant access between these Spreadsheeets to let one get the data from the other